# Google Analytics not working for multiple domains

Tags: google, google-analytics

I have a webapp that allows users to embed an iframe on their website. This iframe contains a Google Analytics snippet that is logging an event that captures the website the iframe is embedded on.

Google Analytics isn't reporting anything, even though I am clearly embedding this iframe on numerous websites (on multiple domains as well).

Does Google Analytics not allow tracking for multiple domains?

Answer (score 1):

Google analytics will report back for the site/page in the iframe. It will not report back for the site/page hosting the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

A default setup of Google Analytics is designed to track content and visitor data for a single domain. Tracking Across Multiple Domains and Sub-domains

- In this scenario, you might want to track two unique domains and one sub-domain. For example, suppose you have an online store and you also want to track visitor and campaign data to your blog.

  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite